# c# refactor code via parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, refactoring

I have this two methods which basically do the same, I was wondering, if it is possible to introduce a new parameter to make these two methods one

Methods:

```
   public string CodeAnalysisEnabled(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName)
    {
        var codeAnalysis = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants("RunCodeAnalysis") select doc).ToArray();

        if (codeAnalysis.Length == 0)
        {
            return groupName + ": RunCodeAnalysis is missing.";
        }

        var allOk = codeAnalysis.All(n => n.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return allOk ? null : groupName + ": RunCodeAnalysis has wrong state.";
    }

    public string WarningsAsErrorsEnabled(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName)
    {
        var codeAnalysis = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants("TreatWarningsAsErrors") select doc).ToArray();

        if (codeAnalysis.Length == 0)
        {
            return groupName + ": TreatWarningsAsErrors is missing.";
        }

        var allOk = codeAnalysis.All(n => n.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return allOk ? null : groupName + ": TreatWarningsAsErrors has wrong state.";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, just add a string parameter. why do you even ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is only one difference which you can pass as argument:

```
public string MeaningfulMethodName(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName, string propertyName)
{
    var codeAnalysis = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants(propertyName) select doc).ToArray();

    if (codeAnalysis.Length == 0)
    {
        return $"{groupName}: {propertyName} is missing.";
    }

    var allOk = codeAnalysis.All(n => n.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return allOk ? null : $"{groupName}: {propertyName} has wrong state.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
    public string CodeAnalysisEnabled(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName)
    {
        return Check(propertyGroup, groupName, "RunCodeAnalysis");
    }

    public string WarningsAsErrorsEnabled(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName)
    {
        return Check(propertyGroup, groupName, "TreatWarningsAsErrors");
    }

    private static string Check(XElement propertyGroup, string groupName, string checkedParam)
    {
        var codeAnalysis = (from doc in propertyGroup?.Descendants(checkedParam) select doc).ToArray();

        if (codeAnalysis.Length == 0)
        {
            return groupName + $": {checkedParam} is missing.";
        }

        var allOk = codeAnalysis.All(n => n.Value.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return allOk ? null : groupName + $": {checkedParam} has wrong state.";
    }
```